# Operator norm in Hilbert space

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $F$.

> If $A\in \mathcal{B}(F)$, why $(\|A^n\|^{1/n})_n$ is a decreasing sequence?

Comment: Because $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$ for all $A,B\in\mathcal B$?

Comment: @Rahul How can I use this formula to show the desired result? Thank you

Comment: $\|A^2\|^{1/2}\le(\|A\|\|A\|)^{1/2}=\|A^1\|^1$, and so on.

Comment: @Rahul: "and so on"... ?

Comment: @Rahul Could you please provide me an answer? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claim is false. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\1/2&0\end{bmatrix}.$ Then $A^2 = I$, $A^3 = A$, $A^4 = I$, and so on. The sequence $(\|A^n\|^{1/n})_n$ is $(2,1,2^{1/3},1,2^{1/5},1,\dots)$.

Comment: Note that while the sequence is not decreasing with respect to $\leq$, it *is* decreasing with respect to the order given by divisibility.

Comment: What do you mean by the  order  given by divisibility?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you ask @tomasz?

Comment: @Schüler: divisibility gives a partial ordering on the set of natural numbers.